# Powershell replace path to file which contains

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a .txt file, which contains some important things. One of them is path to the place where I've store some files. This path is used in two places in that .txt file.

```
"path" : "D:\\final_test\\abc"
```

"abc" is a directory name, and all the time it will be other, because of that I would like to replace that path using get-content and powershell.

I did few try and when I do something like this

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace 'abc', 'XYZ' | Out-file test.txt
```

everything works, but when I did something like this

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace 'D:\\final_test\\abc', 'D:\\final_test\\XYZ' | Out-file test.txt
```

or something like this

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '^D:\\final_test\\.*$', 'D:\\final_test\\XYZ' | Out-file test.txt
```

it won't work (nothing was changed in .txt file).

Of course the best way will be to replace "D:\\final_test\\...." (no matter what will be after "final_test\\").

Can you help me with that somehow? 
I'm not sure, but it looks like there is some problem with "backslash" sign.

Answer (score 3):

Since the backslash character is the escape character in regular expressions, you must double them up in the first part of the -replace command.
This should work:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace 'D:\\\\final_test\\\\abc', 'D:\\final_test\\XYZ' | Out-file test.txt
```

Comment: So yes double backslashes helps, but the question is how to replace "abc" with anything?

I've try with ".*$" or ".+$" but it don't work.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you would only like to replace the part after the initial directory name? In this case just "abc"?
For that i would use `-replace '(D:\\\\final_test\\\\)abc', '$1XYZ`

The brackets around "(D:\\\\final_test\\\\)" capture this part and in the replacement it can be inserted again via the "$1".

Comment: If the "abc" part can be something else each time, this would be better for you: `powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '(?m)(D:\\\\final_test\\\\).*$', '$1XYZ'`"

Comment: If also the replacement filename can be different each time, i suggest you create a variable for that like:

`$newfilename = '$1' + 'whatever';
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '(?m)("D:\\\\final_test\\\\)[^"]+', $newfilename"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure which part of the path you want to change, but try this?

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '^D:\\final_test\\', 'D:\New_Name\' | Out-file test.txt
```

Comment: I would like to change "abc" part, but this part all the time will be different, so because of that I thought about something like this "^D:\\final_test\\*' but when I've tried with that, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

The `-replace` function uses regular expressions thus you have to escape some regex characters. Anyhow, this is the regex I would use:

```
(Get-Content .\test.txt) -replace '(?<="path" : ")[^"]+',  'D:\\final_test\\XYZ' | Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: I tried with that command but I've received "out-file" or "set-content" is not recognized as in internal or exertnal command.

Comment: Which PowerShell Version are you using?

Comment: It's a Windows 7 with PowerShell verison 2.0.-1.-1 if I'm not wrong.
And if I try something like this (after XYZ I added ^" to exit special sign and have in path also double-quote sign)->
> powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace '(?m)(D:\\\\final_test\\\\abc).*$', 'D:\\final_test\\XYZ^"' | Out-file -encoding ASCII test.txt"

I received 

"'out-file' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Do you know how to fix that?